# How to extract cluster membership in weka?

Tags: algorithm, classification, cluster-computing, weka, membership

How to extract cluster membership in weka? Im working on my work and i tried to extract cluster membership through weka. Anyone can help me please. I will be very grateful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you are using WEKA. In the GUI, in Explorer, after you have clustered data, you can right click on the results item. One of the options will be "Visualize cluster assignments".  If you select that,  the visualization window has a Save button that saves the data in an arrf with an additional field that gives the cluster assignment.